# How to create ios smart banner like facebook? It doesnt have meta apple-itunes-app

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, banner, smartbanner

I was wondering how to create smart banner like facebook?
It doesnt have the close button and look condensed comparing to the banner I created (Im using this [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/promoting_apps_with_smart_app_banners](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)).

facebook screenshot
[image: facebook screenshot]

I have investigated the html elements on facebook but it doesnt have meta meta apple-itunes-app. So Im really curious how facebook show the banner.

I tried using meta apple-itunes-app. But the result is different: it's much bigger

result

[image: result]

Answer (score -1):

The Universal Link banner is a ‘smart banner’. The ‘smartness’ in-play here is that it condenses in height when the app is installed.

The documentation ([see here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/promoting_apps_with_smart_app_banners)) states

> the Smart App Banner intelligently changes its action

The documentation shows the two states of the banner as-well.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not answer the question since the second screenshot shows that the app has already been installed (i.e. open button) yet it remains larger.

Comment: @Felicio - There are two kinds of banners that a developer may use. The ‘smart banner’ which is implemented using a meta tag mentioned in the question. This is the larger banner. The second ‘banner’, which is the thin one, is the Universal Link banner. It appears on pages that have a universal link into their app. No HTML meta tag is required for this, instead an apple-app-file-association file needs to be served from a specific location of your website’s server. I hope my comment would help. I will try to find time and update my answer over the weekend to include more information on this.

Comment: Also to your point about the second screenshot @Felicio, the smart banner (the larger one implemented using the HTML meta tag) is also ‘smart’ in the sense that the button shows ‘View’ or ‘Open’ depending on whether the app is installed or not. This banner can also provide deeplink capabilities. However, there are deeper integrations like Apple search indexing that only a Universal link implementation can provide. The universal link banner is an automatic reward when deeplinking is implemented using Universal Links as opposed to other methods.

Comment: And my answer is certainly confusing to say the least and needs a proper edit. Thank you for pointing it out @Felicio.

Comment: This is almost it. 

Could you please state your source for "The second ‘banner’, which is the thin one, is the Universal Link banner"?

Also, what else needs to be done apart "No HTML meta tag is required for this, instead an apple-app-file-association file needs to be served from a specific location of your website’s server."? Matching appID of the iOS app in applinks? Got code examples?